# jQuery.GET intermittent failure in Safari in ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have the following utility function which I use as a standard way of adding headers to an HTTP GET request.

```js
const get1 = function(url, callback) {
    console.log("in get1 with url : " + url);

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
            .then(function(idToken) {
                return {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + idToken,
                    'ACTING_ON_BEHALF_OF': ns.actingAs
                };
            })
            .then(function(headers) {
                resolve($.get({
                    url: url,
                    headers: headers,
                    dataType: "json",
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                        alert(errorThrown);
                        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                }));
            });
    });
};
```

I call it with structures similar to this

```js
const targetUrl = ns.operation + "/" + ns.stage + "/" + ns.category;

utils.get1("/api/gameconfig/v1/oddoneout/" + targetUrl)
    .then(function(data) {
            console.log("THEN Block")
            // blah blah blah
    });
```

This seems to work reliably in all browsers except Safari on iPad where, periodically, the GET request appears to be executed but the `.then` block never gets entered.

Debugging the javascript seems to indicate that the HTTP request is still executing, but the server side seems to think that it has successfully completed the request and returned a response.

I'm at a loss as to why I see this behaviour. There doesn't seem any pattern to it. Sometimes I can make 50 calls without a problem, sometimes it fails more or less immediately.

Any help will be gratefully received - even if it's hints about how to debug this.

I'm using jQuery 3.3.1 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Add an error handler and see what the error is.

Comment: @epascarello : wouldn't the alerts in the error function be called if there was an error?